# Jersey Client post binary data application-octet/stream

Tags: java, jersey-client

I would like to perform a post with binary data using Jersey Client.

The equivalent with curl would be:

```
curl -v --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary "abc" http://example.com
```

I could not find how to do it in the official docs: http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#client

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can invoke a POST request with Entity which encapsulates binary data like this:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://example.com/rest");
Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity("abc", MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
```

Comment: Thanks, I end up using: 
    Builder webResourceBuilder = webResource.getRequestBuilder();
    webResourceBuilder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    byte[] buffer = {'a','b','c'};
    ClientResponse response = webResourceBuilder.post(ClientResponse.class, new     ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));